# Display only characters to the left of a special character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11. We need to remove a semi colon and anything to the right of the semi colon in a set of strings.

The strings may or may not contain a semi colon. If there is no semi colon, we will return the entire string.

I can see using `CASE` to alter the string only if there is a semi colon, but am sure of the syntax to handle the removal of the semi colon and everything that follows the semi colon.

Strings

`123456;789154` would return `123456`

`123456789` would return `123456789`

```
Case
When string1 like ('%;%')
         then substr( …….)  or trim(…)

Else string1

End
As trimmedstring
```

Any and all help/pointers appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)

Comment: What if you have more than one semicolon in the string? Do you need to remove anything starting from the first semicolon?

Comment: in the dataset, there will be only one, but we would want to remove all from the first following should the dataset ever change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have to remove anything starting from the first semicolon in the string, this could be a way:

```
with test(s) as (
    select '123456;789154' from dual union all
    select '123456;789154;567' from dual union all
    select '123456789' from dual
)
select s, 
       case
        when instr(s, ';') = 0 then s
        else substr(s, 1, instr(s, ';')-1)
       end
from test
```

With regular expressions you could get the same result in a more compact, but less efficient way, with:

```
regexp_substr(s, '[^;]*')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select LEFT(Name, Case 
       WHEN CHARINDEX(';', Name) = 0 
       then Len(Name) 
            else CHARINDEX(';', Name)-1 END) from CustomerDetails
```

Comment: left & charindex are not Oracle attributes.